# How to use "MediaTransportControls" for mediaElement on VS 2015 RC?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<MediaElement x:Name="media" Source="/Assets/Drag MS-A.mp3" Width="500" Height="400" AutoPlay="False" MediaOpened="media_MediaOpened" CurrentStateChanged="media_CurrentStateChanged"></MediaElement>
<MediaTransportControls x:Name="control"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsFastForwardButtonVisible="True" IsStopButtonVisible="False" IsPlaybackRateButtonVisible="False" IsVolumeButtonVisible="False"></MediaTransportControls>
```

I really don't found tutorial out. I just saw "SystemMediaTranportsControl" tutorial but still not playing. How to use "MediaTransportControls" for mediaElement on VS 2015 RC?.Everyone help me write this part. Thanks

```
SystemMediaTransportControls systemControls;


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        // Hook up app to system transport controls.
        systemControls = SystemMediaTransportControls.GetForCurrentView();
        systemControls.ButtonPressed += SystemControls_ButtonPressed;

        // Register to handle the following system transpot control buttons.


    }

    private void SystemControls_ButtonPressed(SystemMediaTransportControls sender, SystemMediaTransportControlsButtonPressedEventArgs args)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        switch (args.Button)
        {
            case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Play:
                PlayMedia();
                break;
            case SystemMediaTransportControlsButton.Pause:
                PauseMedia();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    async void PlayMedia()
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            media.Play();
        });
    }

    async void PauseMedia()
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            media.Pause();
        });
    }


    private void media_MediaOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void media_CurrentStateChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (media.CurrentState)
        {
            case MediaElementState.Playing:
                systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Playing;
                break;
            case MediaElementState.Paused:
                systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Paused;
                break;
            case MediaElementState.Stopped:
                systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Stopped;
                break;
            case MediaElementState.Closed:
                systemControls.PlaybackStatus = MediaPlaybackStatus.Closed;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `MediaTransportControls` is not a part of `WPF`.

Comment: I write on universal.. Which did "wpf" support?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls

Answer (score 1):

Your MediaTransportControls need be inside of MediaElement

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement1" Source="ms-appx:///Assets/audio.wma"
              AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
    <MediaElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls IsCompact="True"/>
    </MediaElement.TransportControls>
</MediaElement>
```

You can read more [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediatransportcontrols.aspx)